# Using codeblocks code in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

I am used to write C++ project in CodeBlocks, but for some stupid reasons I have to show it to my teacher in VisualStudio. I tried to make a console app or an empty project, and copied my main file there, but with the first one I get bunch of erorrs and the second one I get 'The system cannot find the way specified'. What is different in VisualStudio? I don't understand at all what is wrong.
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const int kroku = 1000;

const double aa = 0; //pocatecni bod intervalu
const double bb = 1; //konečný bod intervalu

double a; //parametr

const double h = (bb - aa) / kroku; //krok

double p(double t) {  //(py')' - qy = f
return exp(a*pow(t, 2));
}

double q(double t) {
return -exp(a*pow(t, 2))*pow(a, 2)*pow(t, 2);
}

double dp(double t) {
return 2 * t*a*exp(a*pow(t, 2));
}

double y[kroku + 1]; //řešení původní rce
double dydx[kroku + 1];
double z[kroku + 1]; //řešení dílčí rce
double dzdx[kroku + 1];
double x[kroku + 1]; //rozdělení intervalu (aa, bb) po krocích h

void generateX() { //generuje hodnoty x
for (int k = 0; k <= kroku; k++) {
    x[k] = aa + k*h;
}
}

 double partial(double pp1, double pp2, double w[kroku + 1], double dwdx[kroku + 1], double v)//řešení rce (pw')' - qw = g s pp
{
  w[v] = pp1; //inicializace - počáteční podmínka
  dwdx[v] = pp2; //inicialzace - počáteční podmínka

for (int i = 0; i <= kroku; i++) { //substituce dwdx proměnná -> dwdx = (w_(n+1) - w_n)/h) && dwdx =
    w[i + 1] = h*dwdx[i] + w[i];
    dwdx[i + 1] = (h / p(aa + h*i))*(q(aa + h*i)*w[i] - dp(aa + h*i)*dwdx[i]) + dwdx[i];
}
return 0;
}

double omega1, omega2; //nové počáteční podmínky omega1 = y(x0), omega2 = y'(x0)

void print(double N[kroku + 1])
{
fstream file;
file.open("data.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::trunc);//otevření/vytvoření(trunc) souboru
if (file.is_open()) //zápis do souboru
{
    cout << "Writing";
    file << "#" << "X" << " " << "Y" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j <= kroku; j++) {
        file << x[j] << " " << N[j] << endl;
    }
    file << "#end";
}
else
{
    cout << "Somethinq went wrong!";
}
file.close();
}

int main()
{
double alpha; //pocatecni podminka y(aa) = alpha
double beta; //y(bb) = beta
cout << "Assign the value of beta " << endl;
cin >> beta;
cout << "Assign the value of alpha " << endl;
cin >> alpha;
cout << "Assign the value of parameter a" << endl;
cin >> a;
double alpha1 = 0; //alpha1*p(aa)*y'(aa) - beta1*y(aa) = gamma1
                   //double alpha2 = 0; //alpha2*p(bb)*y'(bb) + beta2*y(bb) = gamma2
double beta1 = -1;
double beta2 = 1;
double gamma1 = alpha;
double gamma2 = beta;
generateX();
partial(alpha1, beta1 / p(aa), z, dzdx, aa); //(pz')'-qz = 0
omega1 = gamma2 / beta2;
omega2 = 1 / (z[kroku] * p(bb))*(gamma1 + dzdx[kroku] * p(bb));
partial(omega1, omega2, y, dydx, aa);//(py')' - qy = f = 0
print(y);
return 0;
strong text}
```

when I add

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

I get four errors
2x 'Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type'
2x 'subscript is not of integral type'
for these lines

```
    w[v] = pp1;
dwdx[v] = pp2;
```

Could anyone please help me? Thank you a lot

Comment: `v` is a `double` you can't use floating point numbers for array indexes.

Comment: Instead of adding `stdafx.h` you can select "Not using precompiled headers" in the project settings. The only other error I get is using `double v` as an index - you just cannot access arrays element `1.6`.

Comment: Codeblocks is not a compiler.  The underlying compiler used by Codeblocks is more than likely `g++`.  This compiler allows extensions to the C++ language, by default.  This unfortunately allows you to write code that you really don't know is invalid C++ until you use another compiler, i.e. Visual C++.  Thus it isn't a "stupid reason" to use Visual C++.  Maybe the teacher wants to ensure you're using actually using C++, and not have code littered with extensions to the language.

Answer (score 1):

array subscript v in your line

```
w[v]
```

can not be double. It must be of interger type.